# why Ckeditor gets unloaded if reactStrictMode is set to true in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ckeditor, ckeditor5

so he is my code for initializing the editor

```
  
  const editorRef = useRef()
  const [ editorLoaded, setEditorLoaded ] = useState( false )
  const { CKEditor, ClassicEditor } = editorRef.current || {}

  useEffect( () => {
    editorRef.current = {
      CKEditor: require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react' ).CKEditor,
      ClassicEditor: require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' )
    }
    setEditorLoaded( true )
  }, [] )

    return (
      <div className='w-full h-full' >
      <h1>Ckeditor5 Nextjs</h1>
      {
        editorLoaded ?
        <CKEditor className="mt-3 wrap-ckeditor" editor={ClassicEditor} onReady={editor => {
         console.log(editor);
        }} />
        :
        "loading..."
      }
      

    </div>
    )
}
```

if `reactStrictMode` is set to `true` the editor will load and then unload after a few hundred milliseconds why is this the case ?